# Problem set width in button

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

I'm trying to set a width on a button in Sharepoint online, but the style does not work. It's as if he has a shallow width.

html

```
<button style="height:20px;width:20px;" type="button" id="diminuiAcrescimo">-</button>
```

Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you check your master page or any css files that affect on the button in general something like this:

```
 button {
  width:/*any value*/;!important
  height:/*any value*/;!important
 }
```

If the above solution is not working try to debug your code to obtain where the style is modified.

GoodLuke!

Answer (score 2):

Just add your custom `Class` or `Id` to your button and define the `CSS` for that particular selector.

```
<button style="height:20px;width:20px;" type="button" id="diminuiAcrescimo">-</button>
```

Use like:

```
#diminuiAcrescimo
{
height:value !important;
width:value !important;
}
```

OR

```
<button class='clsButton' style="height:20px;width:20px;" type="button" id="diminuiAcrescimo">-</button>
```

Then

```
.clsButton
 {
 height:value !important;
 width:value !important;
 }
```